# The materials tab appears different than the usual material tab

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, node-editor

when i open my blender a material is applied automatically and i am unable to use the material node editor. The materials tab also appears different than the usual material tab. I am having trouble applying the usual gloss, mix, and other shaders

[image: my current materials tab]

[image: my current materials node editor screen]

[image: previous materials node editor screen]

Comment: The question is not so clear to me. Which renderer do you want to use? Cycles or Blender Internal. The pictures in your question are for Blender Internal, but you're also talking about several shaders in the text of your question that are for Cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes are used to create materials using cycles renderer. You can see "Blender render" selected on top of your Blender window (which is old Blender render and soon is said to be removed with next version), click on it and switch to Cycles to get nodes to work.

Answer (score 1):

Mariusz beat me to it by 4 minutes, but he's right. I ~guess~ you want Cycles. Change your renderer here:
[image]

Comment: yeah thanx, you're right. It skipped my mind that the active renderer affects the materials and textures. thanx again

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the render engine for Blender Render to Cycles Render